# NSTimer usage in Xamarin Ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, nstimer

I am trying to build a App in IOS where I want UIButton to continuously change its background colour.
I tried using Timer was not able to do it properly.
I want the colour background to continuously change colour.
If anyone has any idea please suggest

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```
void StartButton_TouchUpInside (object sender, EventArgs ea) {
_timer = NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
{
    this.InvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
        //Your code goes here
    });
}
```

To Start the Timer

```
_timer.Fire();
```

To End The Timer

```
_timer.Invalidate();
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.